# can i publish code to read a propreitary format under an open source license?

Tags: open-source, licensing, reverse-engineering

we have written a java library to read from a poorly documented format used to store chemical measurements. We completely reverse engineered it - so not a piece of code from the manufacturer.

I would love to go open source with that. But I'm a bit worried I get into some legal hell if I do. Especially I need to assure some legal security for my department.

I was considering an LGPL or Apache license since I also want to distribute it to our partners which might not publish under a free license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: @KevinBrown - Well the guideline seems from 2014 while the question was asked 2011 ;). But since I'm still interested I will aks there again.

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert in this area, but I believe that this is fair use and completely safe - take for example LibreOffice (or OpenOffice.org), which can read Microsoft's poorly documented, non-standard, proprietary office formats through the reverse-engineering skills of its contributors.

Comment: well - seems you are the only reply ;) anyway had hoped for some founded information.